# Correct way to do a distributed mutex in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, concurrency, mutex, distributed

I am building a feature that requires application-level lock functionality.

The feature goes like this:

- user logs in to the site
- they hit a button which kicks off a bunch of API requests (this is a long-running, synchronous, process)
- process finishes and all is well

The issue is that there can only be one instance of this process running at any one time. Any kind of double-submit will cause major problems.

My current strategy is to implement the following logic:

- I will put a boolean field on a table that indicates whether or not the long-running process is currently active
- when the user first submits their action, I will update that boolean using a lock:

> ```
> pc = ProcessControl.first
> pc.with_lock do  
>   if pc.process_is_running?
>     return # abort
>   else
>     pc.process_is_running = true
>     pc.save!
>   end
> end
> LongRunningProcess.start!
> ```

- then, the long process will run, and at the end, I'll flip the flag back to false.

So my question is: will this work in a distributed environment? I have multiple app servers and I want to be sure that once the long-running process is off and running on one of the app servers, any request to kick off the long running process around the same time will read `pc.process_is_running?` and it should return false, preventing the double-submit.

I have found some resources already that indicate there are other ways to do a distributed lock, I'm hoping that this (maybe naive?) approach above will work.

Resources I've looked at:

- http://makandracards.com/makandra/1026-simple-database-mutex-mysql-lock
- https://github.com/mceachen/with_advisory_lock

Comment: What potential issues do you think might be relevant? If you have a single database server and the `ProcessControl.first` is guaranteed to always be the same record, then I'd guess this should work.

Comment: I think it would work fine, considering it's a database-level lock and said database is shared between instances, as @BoraMa has mentioned.

Comment: I dunno.  This code works, I'm sure...but I don't see anything about timeouts, races, ensuring the flag (process_is_running) gets reverted later, etc. For production code, I'd look for an existing tool that covers more of those bases. (I'm doing something similar, and your link to with_advisory_lock looks like a keeper)